# elasticsearch client cant be use in vue.js, because of no nodejs environment

Tags: vue.js, elasticsearch

I tried to use elasticsearch client in vue.js. But elasticseach needs to be in a node.js environment. Vue.js doesn't have node.js environment. Is there any other solution?
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/index.html

Comment: Use a [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/) environment :p . You're trying to use backend technology on the front-end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a rest api an server site.
This Node.js porgramm will create the Connection to elasticsearch Server.

Your vue.js Client Connect you Rest api by ajax call.
You Node.js Programm call elasticesearch.